# API view is empty when Filtering django rest framework view by PK in urls.py

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to filter my APIListView by a PK value specified in the url. The code runs however my API is empty even though i know it has data at the PKs that i am testing. Any Ideas?

**Models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Description
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('pk', 'Description', 'Price')
```

**Views.py (API)**

```
class SingleItemAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        item = self.request.query_params.get('pk', None)
        queryset = Item.objects.filter(pk=item)
        return queryset
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/',SingleItemAPIView.as_view(), name='single_object_view')
]
```

**DRF Output**

```
GET /api/1/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URL parameters can be found in **`self.kwargs`**

```
class SingleItemAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        item = self.kwargs['pk']
        queryset = Item.objects.filter(pk=item)
        return queryset
```